# How is the bar construction on augmented graded algebras a functor?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graded-rings, functors

I have just read (in Algebraic Operads, Loday & Vallette) that the bar construction is a functor $B$ from the category of augmented graded algebras to the category of conilpotent differential graded coalgebras. 
I have seen what this functor does on objects: If $A$ is an augmented graded algebra, then $BA=(T^c(s\bar{A}),d_2)$ is a conilpotent differential graded coalgebra. 
My question is what does this functor do with morphisms of augmented graded algebras?

Comment: Do you have any guess?

Comment: I know it's supposed to be obvious and maybe I should have thought about it/searched for it more before asking here... My guess is for $f:A\to A'$, we define $Bf$ to be the chain map $(f|_\bar{A}^{\otimes n})_n$

Comment: And does that work?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I am however a littles bit confused about what we need the suspension $s$ for, it increases the grades by one but why is this important?

Comment: Never mind i see why the suspension is necessary now, thanks=)